# FPDF function using variable/arrays

Tags: php, arrays, variables, fpdf

some FPDF/php varibale help need.

I am using FPDF to create a PDF,

I have a footer function like the following:

```
function Footer()
{
    $invoicedetails = $results['invoice']->invoice_details; 
    $idetails = explode(", ", $invoicedetails); 
    $invoice_cost = implode(" ", $idetails); 
    $icost = explode(" ", $invoice_cost); 
    $string = $invoice_cost;
    $pattern = '/(?P<first>([^,].*?))-(?P<second>\d+)/';
    preg_match_all($pattern,$string, $matches);
    $detailsinvoice = $matches['first']; 
    $detailscost = $matches['second']; 

    $this->MultiCell(37.5, 10, $Totalcost , 1,'C',0);
}
```

Where it is supposed to show the price of $detailscost.

I have used this exact code in previous pages, and after the

```
 $pdf = new PDF();
 $pdf->AddPage();
```

Of FPDF and it works perfect (After this is also collect and siplays the $detailsinvoice part)
But for some reason it doesnt work in the footer function.

anyone have any tips?

Ian

Comment: Well, to begin with, `$results` pops up from nowhere... Same with `$Totalcost`. Don't you get a notice?

Comment: Ahhh yeah,sorry, I have some code on another page(function) that creates an array of results, and i left of this: $Totalcost = (array_sum($detailscost)); The code works when not used in a footer function, i need to find out how i can use it in a function.

Comment: Thankyou! I have moved the code the creates $results from a function on another page into this (footer) function and now all is hunkey dorey!